# Error when trying to work with css-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, css-loader

While developing with Reactjs, I have problem with css-loader. Basically, this is my `webpack.config`:

```
{
test: /\.css$/,
exclude: /node_modules/,
loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader',
}, {
test: /\.css$/,
include: /node_modules/,
loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
},
```

And this is how I implement the css :

```
import styles from './Home.css';
.
.
.
<FormControl type="text" className={styles['input-search']}/>
```

This is my `Home.css`

```
.input-search{
width: 500px;
}
```

I'm using Hasnode's mern-starter

But there are no css is loaded. What should I do ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Do not use images of code!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to this and see if it works:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
}
```

If that works, then add your `exclude: /node_modules/` and finally, if that works, then add all your crazy `?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap` additions.

Also consider adding a resolve section to your config:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, '../src/components'),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
```

Comment: ah, this may be your problem. It may have nothing to do with webpack - change this line: `<FormControl type="text" className="input-search"/>`

Comment: this doesnt work neither. Problem is, although this input has class "input-search", there are no CSS was generated named "input-search" ( my second image ).

Comment: I added a resolve section that you might consider adding to webpack.. maybe it's not able to find the file.

Comment: try like this {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },